# Two cards are drawn together from a pack of $52$ cards. What is the probability that one is spade and other is king?

Tags: probability

I did it from conditional probability, first the case when we pick one spade first and then pick a king next.

So it is equal to the probability of picking up a spade*probability of picking a king given that we have already picked up a spade so it is equal to 
$\frac{13}{52} * \frac{4}{51}$

And then the probability of picking up a king and a spade $=$ probability of picking up a king*probability of picking up a spade given that we have already picked up a king which is equal to $\frac{4}{52} * \frac{13}{51}$

Now summing up both of these cases, what is wrong in this method ?

Comment: What if the spade you pick first is the king? Then you are less likely to pick a king on the second choice...

Comment: I modified my approach , Now let 's say the first card I pick is a spade , Now the probability that the first card is a spade and the second card is a king = the probability of picking up a spade*probability of picking a king given that we have already picked up a spade =13/52*(4/51+3/51) , Here I am considering the case where the first card drawn which was spade was a king or it was not a king , if it was a king spade then I have remaining 3 choices for king and if it is not a king then I still have 4 choices for king .

Comment: Now the second case when the first card drawn is a king and the second card drawn is a king , so ,the probability of picking up a king and a spade =probability of picking up a king*probability of picking up a spade given that we have already picked up a king which is equal to 4/52*( 12/51+ 13/51) , since if a king was already drawn there may be a possibility that king was already a spade so now remaining choices for spade are 12 and if the king drawn was not a spade then remaining choices for spade are 13

Comment: Now If I sum up these two cases , is there any mistake in this approach ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spadesuit has its own king. So in the $2$nd case if you pick the king of spades, the number of remaining spades is $12$ not $13$. Your $1$st case has a similar error.

You can choose a non-spade king in $3$ ways and for each choice a spade can be chosen in $13$ ways. If you pick the king of spades, another spade can be chosen in $12$ ways. So the required probability is
$$
{3\times 13+12\over\binom{52}{2}}
$$

Comment: I modified my approach , Now let 's say the first card I pick is a spade , Now the probability that the first card is a spade and the second card is a king = the probability of picking up a spade*probability of picking a king given that we have already picked up a spade =13/52*(4/51+3/51) , Here I am considering the case where the first card drawn which was spade was a king or it was not a king , if it was a king spade then I have remaining 3 choices for king and if it is not a king then I still have 4 choices for king .

Comment: Now the second case when the first card drawn is a king and the second card drawn is a king , so ,the probability of picking up a king and a spade =probability of picking up a king*probability of picking up a spade given that we have already picked up a king which is equal to 4/52*( 12/51+ 13/51) , since if a king was already drawn there may be a possibility that king was already a spade so now remaining choices for spade are 12 and if the king drawn was not a spade then remaining choices for spade are 13

Comment: Now If I sum up these two cases , is there any mistake in this approach ?